# The controller receive the answer (undefined) before the service searches the data

Tags: sqlite, cordova, promise

I'm new with promise. I'm trying to receive an answer from the service. LoginController call LoginService.

I debugged it and the controller receive undefined answer, and then I can check that the service return te value.

So I need that the controller wait for the service answer. I tried to use Promise but didn't work.

**I'm working with [Cordova Sqlite](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage)**.

**Controller**

```
function iniciarSesion() {
        loginService.iniciarSesion(vm.username, vm.password, dispositivo, registration)
            .then(function(sesion) {
                console.log("dataControllee:"+JSON.stringify(sesion)); // receive undefined
                if(sesion.success > 0){
                    $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
                            disableAnimate: true,
                            disableBack: true
                    });
                    if(sesion.success == 1){
                        $location.path("/complejo/home");
                        $state.go('app.home');
                    }
                    else if(sesion.success == 2){
                        $location.path("/usuario/home-usuario");
                        $state.go('app.homeusuario');
                    }
                    else{
                        $location.path("/login");
                        $state.go('app.login', {
                            registration: registration
                        });
                    }
                }
                else{
                    var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                    title: 'Hubo un problema',
                    template: 'Hubo un problema al conectarse al servidor. Intente nuevamente.'
                    })

                }
            })
            .catch(function(e){
                var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                    title: 'Hubo un problema',
                    template: e
                });
            });
    }
```

**Service**

```
/funcion para iniciar sesión
    function iniciarSesion(username, password, dispositivo, registration) {
        return remoteDataService.iniciarSesion(username, password, dispositivo, registration)
        .then(function(respuesta) {
                var datos = respuesta.data;
                var status = respuesta.status;
                if(status == 200){   
                    var exito = datos.success;
                    if(exito == 0){
                        return $q.reject(datos);
                    }
                    else if(exito == 1 || exito == 2){
                        return new Promise(function (res, rej) {
                            datos.registration = registration;
                            res(obtenerDatos(datos));
                        });

                    }
                }
                return $q.reject('Hubo un problema al conectarse al servidor. Intente nuevamente.');
            })
        .catch(generarError);
    }

    function obtenerDatos(data, status, headers, config){
        if (data.token) {
            // Agregamos el token al header para cada futura consulta al servidor
            $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + data.token;

            console.log("Obtengo los datosssss");
            db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: 'example.db', location: 'default'});
            // guardamos en la base de datos SQL el token y el id del usuario
            db.transaction(function(tx) {
                tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS exampleTable (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, clave text NOT NULL, valor TEXT NOT NULL, UNIQUE (clave) ON CONFLICT REPLACE)');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT OR REPLACE INTO exampleTable(clave,valor) VALUES (?,?)', ['token', data.token]);
                tx.executeSql('INSERT OR REPLACE INTO exampleTable(clave,valor) VALUES (?,?)', ['usuario', data.identificadorUsuario]);
                tx.executeSql('INSERT OR REPLACE INTO exampleTable(clave,valor) VALUES (?,?)', ['registrationId', data.registration]);
            }, function(error) {
                $q.reject('hubo un error al iniciar sesión.');
            }, function() {
                return new Promise(function (res, rej) {
                    console.log("dataa:"+JSON.stringify(data)); //get the value AFTER the loginController receive undefined answer
                    res(data);
                });
              });
        }
        else {
            return $q.reject('Hubo un problema al conectarse al servidor. Intente nuevamente.');
        }
    }

    //generar error si hubo un problema
    function generarError(e){
        console.log("hasta acá esta definido4: "+JSON.stringify(e));
        debugger;
        if (e.message) {
            return $q.reject(e.message);
        }
        return $q.reject('Hubo un problema al conectarse al servidor. Intente nuevamente.');
    }
```

So.. How can I solve my problem? May be I can refactor my code.

Thanks!

Comment: `iniciarSesion` in the controller doesn't return anything - perhaps that's the problem

Comment: The view call vm.iniciarSesion(). I cant put a return in the implementation of the function

Comment: oh, sorry, yeah, I see that the controller calls the service - the same function name confused me :p

Comment: nevermind - reading code in another language is hard :p

Comment: OK - finally got there ... in `function obtenerDatos` when  `data.token` is truthy, you don't return anything at all - which is same as `return undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `obtenerDatos` doesn't return a Promise when `data.token` is truthy

Wrap the WHOLE body of that function in a new Promise that is returned from that function. this also means you don't need to use `$q.reject`

```
function obtenerDatos(data, status, headers, config){
    return new Promise(function (res, rej) {
        if (data.token) {
            // Agregamos el token al header para cada futura consulta al servidor
            $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + data.token;

            console.log("Obtengo los datosssss");
            db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: 'example.db', location: 'default'});
            // guardamos en la base de datos SQL el token y el id del usuario
            db.transaction(function(tx) {
                tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS exampleTable (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, clave text NOT NULL, valor TEXT NOT NULL, UNIQUE (clave) ON CONFLICT REPLACE)');
                tx.executeSql('INSERT OR REPLACE INTO exampleTable(clave,valor) VALUES (?,?)', ['token', data.token]);
                tx.executeSql('INSERT OR REPLACE INTO exampleTable(clave,valor) VALUES (?,?)', ['usuario', data.identificadorUsuario]);
                tx.executeSql('INSERT OR REPLACE INTO exampleTable(clave,valor) VALUES (?,?)', ['registrationId', data.registration]);
            }, function(error) {
                rej('hubo un error al iniciar sesión.');
            }, function() {
                console.log("dataa:"+JSON.stringify(data)); //get the value AFTER the loginController receive undefined answer
                res(data);
            });
        }
        else {
            rej('Hubo un problema al conectarse al servidor. Intente nuevamente.');
        }
    });
}
```

another code change I'd recommend - to avoid the promise constructor anti-pattern

**Service**

```
function iniciarSesion(username, password, dispositivo, registration) {
    return remoteDataService.iniciarSesion(username, password, dispositivo, registration)
    .then(function(respuesta) {
        var datos = respuesta.data;
        var status = respuesta.status;
        if (status == 200) {
            var exito = datos.success;
            if (exito == 0) {
                // use throw to reject the Promise returned by .then
                throw datos;
            } else if (exito == 1 || exito == 2) {
                datos.registration = registration;
                // return the obtenerDatos Promise, no need to create one
                return obtenerDatos(datos);
            }
        }
        // use throw to reject the Promise returned by .then
        throw 'Hubo un problema al conectarse al servidor. Intente nuevamente.';
    })
    .catch(generarError);
}
```